# Can af_unix socket with SOCK_SEQPACKET be limited to hundreds of bytes?

Tags: linux, networking

I'm using a af_unix socket to transfer data between applications. Because the receiver/server is slow, allowing the client to write thousands of bytes of data is undesirable. I've seen that the size minimum is 2048. Is there some way to make this much smaller? Hundreds of bytes even? Or limit the socket to a small number of messages instead?

I tried setting both SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF to 512 via setsockopt() and the values seem pegged at 4608 for SO_SNDBUF and 2304 for SO_RCVBUF.

Comment: Probably bytes send can be limited using `SO_SNDBUF` socket option with [setsockopt](http://www.sbras.ru/cgi-bin/www/unix_help/unix-man?setsockopt+2) call.

Comment: Added a comment about trying to set SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF and the values they are after calling setsockopt().